# How to make combobox accessible to other form

Tags: c#, combobox, access-modifiers

I have a combobox1 on form1, but i wanna access it on form2 (able to full edit)
is it possible by turning it public and using

```
form1.comboBox1_ChangedItem(blablabla)
{
// stuff
 }
```

?

Edit: there was a answer here, i was trying to implement it but it got deleted.. what happened?

Comment: yes, just make the comboBox1 a public property.

Comment: i made it, but its not recognizing it, I'm adding a item in form2 via   `Form1.ComboxBox1.Items.Add("item3");` but says Form1 does not contain a definition for ComboBox1

Comment: post your code.  Show the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a combobox public does violates the rules of object-oriented. Better way is use a property to do this.

```
 Public ComboBox1
 {
      get { return this.comboBox1;  }
      set { comboBox1 = value; }
 }
```